# How to assign associate products to a grouped product programmatically?

Tags: magento-1.8, grouped-products, create, associate-products

I've created a grouped product programetically. And want too map associate products to it. I tried the following code which didn't work.
first way:

```
$gProduct->setGroupedLinkData(array($id1,$id2));
```

second way:

```
$gProduct->setAssociatedProducts(array($id1,$id2));
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your associated products array should be like this

```
$data = array();
$data[$simpleId] = array('qty' => 9, 'position' => 0);
$data[$simple2Id] = array('qty' => 3, 'position' => 0);
$grouped->setGroupedLinkData($data);
$grouped->save();
```

Comment: But by default added with status = 0, disabled, how can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code that worked for me.

```
 $associated = array();
$position = 0;

foreach($childrenIds as $productId) {

    $position++;
    $productRepository = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
    $linkedProduct = $productRepository->getById($productId);
    $productLink = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface');
    $productLink->setSku($product->getSku())
        ->setLinkType('associated')
        ->setLinkedProductSku($linkedProduct->getSku())
        ->setLinkedProductType($linkedProduct->getTypeId())
        ->setPosition($position)
        ->getExtensionAttributes()
        ->setQty(1);

    $associated[] = $productLink;


}


$product->setProductLinks($associated);
$product->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code also work but that is not the best way.

```
 $q = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
 $q->getConnection('core_write')->query("insert into catalog_product_link (linked_product_id, product_id,link_type_id) values (".$newSimpleProdId.",".$grpProdId.",2)");
```